# Drop down menu with image switch

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do an image switch out depending on what a person picks in a drop down menu. The html and the js are in two different files.

This is just part of the html:

```
 <select id="Breed_0_field" name="Breed76" onChange="javascript: wizard();" onkeyup="javascript: wizard();" tabindex="4">
 <option selected="selected" value="Select One">Select One</option>
 <option value="Other/Mix">Other/Mix</option>
 <option value="0">--- Common Breeds----</option>
 <option value="Border Collie">Border Collie</option>
 <option value="Boxer">Boxer</option>
 <option value="Corgi">Corgi</option>
 <option value="Dachshund">Dachshund</option>
```

For the JS part:

```
 breed = document.getElementById("Breed_0_field").value;
 selectdog()

function selectdog()
{
dog_type=0

switch (breed)
{


case "Affenpinscher": // Affenpinscher
    // Affenpinscher
    document.getElementById("dog_breed_picture").src = "http://handicappedpet.net/helppets/images/avatars/gallery/Dog_Larger/blank.gif";
    break;
case "Affenpinscher": // Affenpinscher
    // Affenpinscher
    document.getElementById("dog_breed_picture").src = "http://handicappedpet.net/helppets/images/avatars/gallery/Dog_Larger/Affenpinscher.gif";
    break;
case "Afghan Hound": // Afghan Hound
    // Afghan Hound
    document.getElementById("dog_breed_picture").src = "http://handicappedpet.net/helppets/images/avatars/gallery/Dog_Larger/Afghan_Hound.gif";
    break;
```

The problem is, is that this all use to work for numbers. The value in html part use to be 1,2,3,4...and the correct image matched the case with 1,2,3,4...but I need the value for the html to be it's name otherwise later on down the code it only shows the number instead of the breed name.

How do I made this image switch kinda work but with a string instead of numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad! Apparently this does actually work!

My problem was that I had a function 
       if (breed > 0){selectdog()}
Which would never work because i'm no long using numbers.

But you can indeed use strings with case.

Answer (score -1):

what you could do is have an array with the dogs names, the numbers referencing an index in the array that you could use later in the code. I can include an example if it would help